# Manga/web novel/story about a wealthy woman who dies of old age and is reincarnated as an orphan girl in the slums

Tags: story-identification, novel, manga, reincarnation

A old woman is at the end of her life, but she's wealthy and is known for helping the poor, so she donates her wealth to charities upon her death.

She comes back to life in the body of an orphan girl in a ditch in the slums, her father having thrown her out. I can't remember why. Somehow, she ends up gaining a sister and a new family. I think through modern cooking styles or something like that. Like cooking fried meat in a pot, not roasted over a large uncontrolled fire.

Although I could be thinking of two different stories. I do remember it being an old woman turning into a young girl again. And living the live she always wanted, with a family.